# Is it possible to add the CRUD actions to a infolist in Filament PHP v3?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-filament, filamentphp

[image: this is what i get]

[image: this is whati want]

I want to give the user ability to change stuff in the table, so is it possible to apply crud-opertaion-actions to my table inside a infolist.

Currently nothing appears but the crud-actions are set, so what should i do get it to appear?

```
public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->recordTitleAttribute('firstname')
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('lastname')
                    ->sortable()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->placeholder('none')
                    ->alignLeft()
                    ->label(__('messages.lastname')),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->headerActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make(),

                Tables\Actions\Action::make('bearbeiten')
                    ->url(fn (CompanyAdvisor $record): string => CompanyAdvisorResource::getUrl('edit', ['record' => $record])),

            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
```

Above is my table-function. the added custom action works but nothing else appears.
How can I get it to appear?